# Socket IO/ React function Not retrieving proper values

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

Hello I am having quite a bit of trouble getting the Socket IO functions to play nicely with my React components.

The gist of it is I am passing down a socket io function down to a child component which creates an onclick handler out of it.

My expected behaviour is that it will bring back the value gained from an element so I can make a message like "x Just subscribed"

The actual behaviour is that the default value "Hello user!" is concatenated with the "Just subscribed" message without the value. Example: "Hello user! Just subscribed!" (missing the name of the thing they are subscribing to)

Here are the socket IO functions and the component I want to pass the function down to

```
send = () => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint)
    socket.emit('change message', this.state.message) 
  }



setMessage(message){
    this.setState({ message })
    this.send()
  }


render() {

    const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint)

server

    socket.on('change message', (message_) => {
        this.setState({message: message_})
    })

return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p> {this.state.message} </p>
      <div>
        <Dashboard setMessage={this.setMessage.bind(this)} />
     </div>
```

And the child Component which I am passing the function to looks like this

```
const data = dataObj.map((dataObj) =>

        <tr> 
            <td >{dataObj.rank}</td> 
            <td >{dataObj.name}</td> 
            <td >{dataObj.symbol}</td>
            <td >{dataObj.price_btc}</td>  
            <td >{dataObj.available_supply}</td>
            <td >{dataObj.total_supply}</td>  
            <td >{dataObj.percent_change_24h}</td> 
            <td >{dataObj.price_usd}</td>
            <form action='http://localhost:5000/api/user/108508262530528259904/currencies' method='POST'>
                <input hidden value={dataObj.name} name='name'></input>
                <input hidden value={dataObj.symbol} name='symbol'></input>
                <input hidden value={dataObj.price_usd} name='priceAtSubscription'></input>
                <Button type="submit" id={dataObj.name} onClick={this.props.setMessage} bsStyle="primary">Subscribe</Button> 
            </form>
        </tr>
```

On the server side I handle the event like this

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('New client connected')

  socket.on('change message', (message) => {


    message = message + ' Just gained a new subscriber!'
    console.log('message Changed to: ', message)
    io.sockets.emit('change message', message)
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected')
  })
})
```